# Aliasing piping operations in bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, grep

I frequently will do something like `grep -R foo .` at the root of a project. It’s helpful but the results get diluted by the inclusion of binary. temp, and test files that I don’t care about. So I end up affixing `2>&1 | grep -vE “Binary|/tmp/|/test/“`, which filters out the stuff I don’t care about. Problem is, its a pain to type each time. Everything including and after the 2>&1 stays the same from query to query. So I want to put it in an alias of sorts that would let me `grep -R foo . <thingie>`, where thingie is something fairly short. I’ve tried aliases and environment variables but aliases only work if theyre the first word on the line, and environment vars I can expand with `${thingie}` but the piping seems to get screwed up in the process. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: If I understand your requirements,  you could write a function and install the function in a bash start up file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a function is the way to go. If you have GNU grep

1. use the `--exclude-dir` option so the recursive search does not even bother with it.
2. use the `--binary-files=without-match` option to ignore binary files (alias `-I`).

So:

```
mygrep() {
    grep -R --exclude-dir=tmp --exclude-dir=test -I "$@" .
}
```

Then call

```
mygrep Foo
mygrep -i foo
mygrep -E '(foo|bar)baz'
```